# Publishing Report PDFs Monthly - multiple permissions to view them

Tags: publishing, reporting-services, pdf, reports, document-converter

We have about 30 reports a month to publish.  Each report will have a different set of security rights.  (For example, office manager x should only be able to see his/her report.  But there are a few people who should be able to see all of them.)

Is it practical to use SharePoint for this?  If so, what's the best strategy?  Could it be automated?

We thought of using SSRS for this instead, but we need to review the PDFs before publishing them and that seemed to be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needing to review and approve content is precisely one of SharePoint's core use-cases, so that requirement is definitely not an issue :)

I would have the reports sent to separate Document Libraries, with permissions set up so only the relevant people can view them. Set up Content Approval on those libraries, so when they are added, they need to be viewed and marked as "approved" before everyone can see them.

Integration of SSRS with SharePoint should make this quite a feasible project.

Comment: Congrats on the 10K James!

Comment: Haha, cheers! xD

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to create dedicated document libraries with the appropriate permissions and publish your reports to those libraries.  How you would automate placing the files there, depends on how/where you generate them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  We will just use PDFs for now.  What I'd like to automate is not uploading the files so much, but applying their security.

Comment: Interesting, we were just going to use one library.  So if we have multiple libraries, say one for each Office Mangager, then the security would be on the library itself and all that would have to be done is uploading the new file(s)?

Comment: Yes, set up the permissions to the library and just automate the transferring the files into the libraries. You could also have another "public" document library for the PDFs you want multiple managers to be able to access.